# Child process not killed when starting another one immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following functions

```
let process = null;

const runCommand = () => {
  process = spawn('some command', [], { shell: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'pipe'] });
}

const killProcess = () => {
  if(process !== null) {
    process.kill('SIGKILL');
  }
}

const restartProcess = () => {
  killProcess();
  runCommand();
}
```

When I run `restartProcess`, it must kill current process and start a new one. But current process won't be killed. It stays alive and a new one starts.

If I use `setTimeout` for starting process with a delay after killing, there's no problem (like 6 or 7 seconds). But when it's immediate, there's the problem.

**UPDATE: When I run `killProcess` on its own, all buggy processes will be killed. For instance the bug in `restartProcess` caused 4 concurrent processes to run. `killProcess` kills them all.**

Comment: From the docs: _"Even though the name of this function is `process.kill()`, it is really just a signal sender, like the kill system call. The signal sent may do something other than kill the target process."_

Comment: @Wyck Yes. But it's a bug actually. I provided related link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
let process = null;

const runCommand = () => {
  process = spawn('some command', [], { shell: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'pipe'] });
}

const killProcess = () => {
  if(process !== null) {
    process.kill('SIGTERM');
    process = null; // reset process variable
  }
}

const restartProcess = () => {
  killProcess();
  if (process === null) {
    // start new process only if current process has completely exited
    process = runCommand();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `process.on` don't exists if `process` is`null`

Comment: You are correct. I'll fix it now.

Comment: `if (process === null) { if (process !== null) { … } }`?

Comment: Then I need to sleep :D Maybe this is correct now?

Comment: Tried. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I handle that error trying **waiting the process to end with a flag**. You could do a `SIGTERM` or force a kill with `SIGKILL`.

The flag must be `false` when process start and should be `true` when execute the `onExit` function.

Example:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

let process = null;
let finished = false;

const runCommand = () => {
    console.log("exec");
    process = spawn('sleep 1', [], { shell: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'pipe'] });
    finished = false;

    // When exit, change finished flag
    process.on("exit", () => {
        console.log("finished");
        finished = true;
    });
}

const waitProcessEnd = async () => {
    console.log("waiting");
    // Wait till end
    return new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(function __waitEnds() {
            if (finished) {
                console.log("waiting ends");
                res(true);
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(__waitEnds, 1);
        }, 1);
    });
}

const killProcess = async () => {
    // No process or finished
    if (process === null || finished) {
        return;
    }

    // forcing kill process
    console.log("kill");
    process.kill("SIGKILL");

    // Wait to end
    return await waitProcessEnd();
}

const restartProcess = async () => {
    console.log("restart");
    await killProcess();
    runCommand();
}

(async () => {
    runCommand();
    await waitProcessEnd();
    await restartProcess();
    await restartProcess();
})();
```

**output:**

```
exec // Exec first process
waiting // Waiting to end
finished // The process finished and change the flag
waiting ends // Waiting ends
restart // Restart function (not kill cuz process is end)
exec // Exec second process
restart // Restart function
kill // Kill signal
waiting // Waiting the second process
finished // Finished the second process (flag true)
waiting ends // Waiting ends
exec // Exec the third process
finished // Ends the third process
```

***NOTE:** You must handle the `waitProcessEnd` with a timeout because you must give a change to nodejs to execute the `process.on` function when process end. If you make a while you didn't give that chance to node*

**UPDATE:**

For secure deep killing process and all subprocess you could use a UNIX `pgrep` command to ensure all subprocess of a process deeply and kill each by each. You could combine the next code with the `waitProcessEnd` function.

I made some examples and get the best way is use this steps:

1. STOP the process
2. GET chillds
3. KILL the process
4. repeat for each child

For example I have the file:

**myProcess.sh:**

```bash
sleep 15  &
sleep 20
```

and the next code:

```
async function forceDeepKill(pid) {
    // First should try to stop the process to prevent release more subprocess
    try {
        process.kill(Number(pid), "SIGSTOP");
    } catch (err) {
        // Must be killed
        console.log("NOT STOP", pid);
    }

    // Get childs
    let childs = [];
    try {
        const pr = new spawnSync(`pgrep`, ["-P", pid], { encoding: "utf8" });
        childs = pr.stdout.split("\n");
    } catch (err) {
        // If error, the process ends, killed or not childs
        console.log("NOT CHILDS", pid);
    }

    // Kill the childs
    for (const child of childs) {
        // Could be an empty string
        if (child) {
            forceDeepKill(child);
        }
    }

    // Force kill process
    try {
        console.log("KILLING", pid)
        process.kill(Number(pid), "SIGKILL");
    } catch (err) {
        // Must be killed
        console.log("KILLING", pid)
    }
}

(async () => {
    console.log("EXEC");
    const shProcess = spawn('sh', ["myProcess.sh"], { shell: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'pipe'] });
    // await sleep(100); // make another output
    console.log("DEEP KILL");
    forceDeepKill(shProcess.pid);
    console.log("END");
})();
```

The output must be:

```
EXEC
DEEP KILL
KILLING 13816
END
```

But if you uncomment `await sleep(100);` the output generated will be:

```
EXEC
DEEP KILL
KILLING 13874
KILLING 13875
KILLING 13873
END
```

Some NOTES:

1. If you don't stop the process and only list childs and kill the parent, there is a gap when another subprocess will be started and you will never figure it.
2. If you kill the parent first the subprocess will get a new parent and you will never figure it as a childs. So, you need to conserve the parent, get the childs, and kill parent. (Thats why we stop the parent)
3. The `SIGSTOP` cant be ignored. But if you have a another process to check the parent and release it you  will need to handle this problem with other solution (but this is not the case)

Comment: Have you experienced the same problem before?

Comment: Yes, I was working with AWS HSM binaries and in all my attempts I discover this is the best way to handle when process finished. I hope the problem to be solved for you. I use `SIGKILL` because with `SIGTERM` the HSM binary never ends

Comment: didn´t work? you should use async/await

Comment: I tried simplified version of your code. Changed `killProcess` to a `Promise`, and inside it, attached `on exit` listener to process and put `resolve()` inside its handler. So `killProcess` is a promise that only resolves when process `exit` event is emitted. Unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: If the process ends and the `onExit` dind't exec will never fire. In that case you could change the `No process or finished` to `process === null || process.exitCode !== null || process.killed` and if that line is inside your promise you could put `res(true); return;` after that set the `process.on("exit"` and after that the `process.kill("SIGKILL");`

Comment: But, if you use the `setInterval` works well? Because this will be my best solution for all my cases in  the HSM binaries

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could find the problem and solution. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: `pgrep -P [PID]` is a good way to get attached processes to `sh`. Well done. I add it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, only remember you must get the childs first before kill the parent. And if you want ensure the process don't make another subprocess you could stop it before get the childs list

Answer (score 1):

After hours of investigation, I could figure it out.

**What is the problem?**

When you run a process using `spawn` and with `shell:true`, if you monitor your processes, you'll see something like this

```
process         pid
sh              24550137
realCommand     24550138
```

So it uses a wrapper around your real command. `process.pid` gives you the pid of `sh`, and all your play with process like `process.kill()` etc. is with `sh`, not with your real running process.

The problem is that `process.kill()` kills `sh`, but real command keeps running.

**Why is it happening?**

It is a bug in NodeJS, based on GitHub thread here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37518

**How did I solve it?**

By monitoring my processes, I noticed that the pid of my real command is always one more than `sh` wrapper. So I updated my function (`killProcess`) like below, to kill it directly:

```
const killProcess = () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        const wrapperPid = process.pid;
        const realPid = Number(wrapperPid) + 1;
        process.kill(wrapperPid, 'SIGKILL');
        process.kill(realPid, 'SIGKILL');

        const waitForKill = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let count = 0;
          const check = () => {

            count++;
            if(count === 9) return reject();//Reject after 4 seconds of failure

            try {
              process.kill(realPid, 0);//throws an error if there's no process with that pid
            } catch (e) {//No process anymore. Resolve
              clearInterval(interval);
              resolve();
            }

          }
          let interval = setInterval(check, 500);
        });

        await Promise.all([waitForKill]);

        resolve();

  });
};
```

It's working now. The only part I worry about is getting real pid from wrapper pid. Maybe it wouldn't be always 1 more that wrapper pid.
**If you know a better way to get the real pid, please let me know.**

**UPDATE:**
Based on @jtwalters answer, you can use `pgrep -P [PID]` to get PIDs of attached commands to `sh`.

Comment: Can you confirm me if the program you run is a shell script and inside it has another commands? I think thats why you have two process (or even more)

Comment: @jtwalters No what I run is not shell itself. Node `spawn` uses a shell wrapper. It's a bug. I could find a thread in GitHub about it.

Comment: Oh thats crazy, witch version of nodejs you have? I have a MacOS 13.2 with NodeJS v18.14.0 and I can only reproduce the same output if I run a `sh myscript.sh` with a command inside

Comment: PD: I make an update in my answer to ensure you kill the all the child process of the spawn and not another process in case will be generated by your OS :)

Comment: @jtwalters Thanks. I'm running node 16.14.0 in Ubuntu 20.04.3 TLS. I don't know if the same problem exists with Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like all of your code - the bug is most likely in your "main" function.. So, the reason it's leaving process open is due to something you aren't showing us - how you are using those functions..

The code below should help clear this up for you..

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const cmd = 'bash';

let process = null;

const runCommand = () => {
  process = spawn(cmd, [], { shell: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'pipe'] });
  console.log('started new process : pid =', process.pid);
}

const killProcess = () => {
  if (process !== null) {
    console.log('killing existing process: pid =', process.pid, '\n');
    process.kill('SIGKILL');
    process = null;
  }
}

const restartProcess = () => {
  killProcess();
  runCommand();
}

// "main"
(() => {
  runCommand();
  setTimeout(() => {
    // restart the existing process after 4 seconds
    restartProcess();
  }, 4000);
})();
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

### Update

Per our convo in the comments - like how are you actually using these functions? Are you doing something like this:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const cmd = 'bash';

let process = null;

const runCommand = () => {
  process = spawn(cmd, [], { shell: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'pipe'] });
  console.log('started new process : pid =', process.pid);
}

const killProcess = () => {
  if (process !== null) {
    console.log('killing existing process: pid =', process.pid, '\n');
    process.kill('SIGKILL');
    process = null;
  }
}

const restartProcess = () => {
  killProcess();
  runCommand();
}

// "main"
// Are you doing something like this? -
runCommand();
restartProcess();
restartProcess();
// etc... like how are you using those functions to spawn 4 children?
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get why you run `restartProcess` at the beginning, and then run it again after 4 seconds, and then kill it after 2 seconds.

Comment: It's just a way to get the initial child process spawned. Since your `restartProcess` function contains the `runCommand` function. I went ahead and updated it. That is simulating creating multiple child processes - which you should see how they exit properly. It's hard to diagnose what is wrong with your code when we can't see all off it. Would you mind sharing your entire script?

Comment: Entire code is massive. I can't provide it even if I want to. That part reproduces the problem. One important thing that I noticed (as I mentioned in question update) is that all spawned processes are attached to one variable. `process.kill()` kills all of them. Cause I thought that variable will be replaced. Setting it to `null` after killing also makes no difference.

Comment: Could you maybe write something smaller that reproduces your error/issue? Like a minimal reproducible example? Also, I was wrong about the second `setTimeout` - I went ahead and commented it out.  At any rate, it's difficult to understand your issue when I can't reproduce it.  Can you rewrite the script I wrote to mimic the same behavior of your script? Are you spawning like 4 child processes? Just need more info on *how* you're using those functions..

Comment: Process must be 1 at a time, not more. But because of that bug, it start to become concurrent processes as many as I run `restartProcess`. I appreciate your help. It's 4 A.M here. I'll test your solution and will comment here.

Comment: Sounds good. You'll need to rewrite my script to mirror what you're actually doing though. Like an example of how you're using those functions, but simplified.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could find the problem and solution. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: @SoroushBgm nice job! I actually started writing something with Promises as well bc it sounded like you wanted to wait for a process to finish before starting a new one. Very informative answer and I'm glad you got it resolved! Cheers.